# Adding a Content Editor Content Link causes other Web Parts to have a truncated title

Tags: content-editor-web-part

In SharePoint 2013, I added a Content Editor Web Part and then specified a Content Link.  After I did that, other Web Part titles were truncated on the left hand side.  This side effect even extended to pop-up windows.

Comment: What is the Content Editor Web Part doing?  Is there some code that is targeting all web part titles?

Comment: The content editor content link is providing a simple HTML string that provides an URL for the target list and an URL for a help page.  Being an unsophisticated user, I edited the HTML in Word and saved it in content filtered HTML.  When I view source I notice that a whole bunch of CSS tags are still being redefined but why does the scope of the CSS changes extend beyond the page I'm working on.  This doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Word is not a webeditor and adds a whole lot of CSS. Use SharePoint Designer.

Comment: OK, I'll try that.

Comment: Stripping out all of the style definitions introduced by Microsoft Word solved the problem.  I guess in Word, even when you select to save as Web Page, Filtered it still doesn't filter out the style definitions.

I had to go back to the "old days" and edit the HTML in NotePad.

Comment: I would have liked to have used SharePoint Designer but it did a weird thing to my code.  I was using hrefs of the form:

<a href="/sites/proj/Pages/Help.aspx#_3__" target=HelpTxt>

For some unknown reason SharePoint Designer didn't like the named target=HelpTxt tag.  It kept stripping it out.  Its strange because I know SharePoint Designer allows target="_blank" as a tag.

Answer (score 2):

Stripping out all of the style definitions introduced by Microsoft Word solved the problem. I guess in Word, even when you select to save as Web Page, Filtered it still doesn't filter out the style definitions. I had to go back to the "old days" and edit the HTML in NotePad.

I would have liked to have used SharePoint Designer but it did a weird thing to my code. I was using hrefs of the form:  For some unknown reason SharePoint Designer didn't like the named target=HelpTxt tag. It kept stripping it out. Its strange because I know SharePoint Designer allows target="_blank" as a tag.